# error when exporting a project Android with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

while I export a ADT project in eclipse I find some issue but i don't know the cause . here a capture of my problem

[image]

Comment: 1) Why still using Eclipse? 2) Did you download and setup the SDK? I don't think android comes with those `javax` packages

Comment: yes I installed the SDK

Comment: have you checked your project's classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click on the error message and import the java library. Make sure you also set the JDK in the build path of eclipse. After that clean and rebuild the project. Please do check the following screenshot. The below screenshot is an example, neglect the WebSphere Application Server v7.0JRE. Also make sure you point the JRE path to `jdk1.8.x\jre`

[image]